# Can funct (v) be used as synonym of function(v)?

Tags: vocabulary

There is a word **Defunct** which means to make inactive or dead but there is no word like funct although function is used as a verb. 
Why we can't use funct? Why can't we use root funct as it is?

Comment: Of course you can.  The question is, will you be understood if you do?  People will be unfamiliar with it and would want to look it up. When they did they would find that it wasn’t in the dictionary and then they’d be stuck wondering what you meant by it and why you didn’t use words they recognized.

Comment: There are surely more popularly accepted words that carry the same meaning; there's no need to ambiguate, and even reckful, ruthful usage will not make it gainly and wieldy among chalant writers. As Jim notes, you may be gruntled trying to popularize it, but being more corrigible, I am consolate being trepid.

Comment: The word "[defunct](http://www.onelook.com/?w=defunct&ls=a)" is used as an adjective, not as a verb. It means "inactive or dead" not "to make inactive or dead".

Comment: @Jim There are authorities asserting that unless a string is in the recognised lexicon, it's not a word. Perhaps a candidate- or pseudo-word, perhaps gibberish.

Answer (score 1):

Funct- is the past participle of the Latin term  "fungi"  (to discharge, execute) which found collocation in terms like defunct, function, functional, malfunction, perfunctory, but it didn't develop into a verb itself:

[defunct](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=defunct&allowed_in_frame=0) (adj.):

> - 1590s, from Old French defunct (14c., Modern French defunt) or directly from Latin defunctus "dead," literally "off-duty," ***from past participle of defungi "to discharge, finish," from de- "off,***  completely" (see de-) + fungi "perform or discharge duty" (see function (n.)).

[function](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=function&allowed_in_frame=0) (n.):

> - 1530s, "one's proper work or purpose; power of acting in a specific proper way," from Middle French fonction (16c.) and directly from Latin functionem (nominative functio) "a performance, an execution," noun of action ***from funct-, past participle stem of fungi "perform, execute, discharge,"***  from PIE *bhung- "be of use, be used".

Comment: Would be better if you provide verb. Defunct & function both can be verb as well.

Comment: @Aghori - defunct is an adjective, not a verb. Function is also a verb, but the etymology of the noun predates the verb by a few centuries.

Comment: Defunct is verb as well - showing in my English dictionary app.

Comment: @Aghori - I can't find its definition as a verb, can you post yours? https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/defunct - http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/defunct

Comment: Using this one - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=livio.pack.lang.en_US

Comment: @Aghori Wiktionary, like all crowd-sourced references, should be used with caution. It's highly unlikely you will see *defunct* used as a verb in any quality journalism or literature in a major English-speaking country. But yes, you can use it as a verb— in the same way that more or less [*any* word can be used as a verb](http://www.gocomics.com/calvinandhobbes/1993/01/25) in English, at least casually.